# Converting time series into a heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, heatmap

I'm looking for a good transformation in pandas which would allow me to go from a time series of measurements into a count-per-bin-per-timebin list.

Let's say I've got my:

```
x = list(range(count))
y = [random.gauss(1, 0.1) for _ in range(count)]
```

I can transform this into binned intervals on both sides:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict({'x': x, 'y': y})
df['x'].update(pandas.cut(df['x'], 20))
df['y'].update(pandas.cut(df['y'], 20))
```

I know I can get the value counts for the `y`s using:

```
df['y'].value_counts()
```

But I'm having trouble putting the "run value_counts on `y` grouped by unique `x` values, then unroll, and return that" into a valid operation.

---

Example:

```
y = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
bin_count = 2
```

expected:

```
df: x    y  count
    0-2  1  2
    0-2  2  1
    3-5  3  1
    3-5  4  2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
y = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
bin_count = 2
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'x': x, 'y': y})
df['x'].update(pd.cut(df['x'], bin_count))

df1 = df.groupby('x')['y'].value_counts().reset_index(name='count')
print (df1)
               x  y  count
0  (-0.005, 2.5]  1      2
1  (-0.005, 2.5]  2      1
2     (2.5, 5.0]  4      2
3     (2.5, 5.0]  3      1
```

For columns from `y` use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('x')['y'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df1)
y              1  2  3  4
x                        
(-0.005, 2.5]  2  1  0  0
(2.5, 5.0]     0  0  1  2
```

EDIT:

If need unique values for bins add parameter `labels=False` to [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
df['x'].update(pd.cut(df['x'], bin_count, labels=False))

df1 = df.groupby('x')['y'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df1)
y  1  2  3  4
x            
0  2  1  0  0
1  0  0  1  2
```